# Can't connect outside subnet on Centos 7

Tags: networking, centos7, linux-networking

I have a server running Centos 7 with the following network configuration:

```
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
IPADDR=192.168.1.5
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
PREFIX=24
DNS1=192.168.6.3
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
NAME="Wired connection 2"
DEVICE="em2"
UUID=9a0ef963-195a-3d04-9ef2-377c1930c37a
HWADDR=74:86:7A:F3:BA:46
ONBOOT=yes
AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=-999
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
DHCPV6C=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

/etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
HOSTNAME=d6host.co.uk
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em2
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 em2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2
```

I have another server running Centos 6 and almost the same configuration on 192.168.1.3. I am able to ping 192.168.1.3, I can SSH to and from it to the other machines on the subnet, but I am not able to connect outside the local network. At first, I thought this might be a firewall issue, but I have tried disabling the firewall and I still can't connect to any IPs outwith the subnet. See:

ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

```
PING www.google.com (216.58.212.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
148 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 146999ms
```

I'm a little stumped as to what might be causing this. Are there any obvious errors or other steps that might help me to debug this?

Edit: Firewall info (firewallid):

firewall-cmd --list-all

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: em2 lo
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client dns http https mysql ssh
  ports: 9200/tcp 6081/tcp 10000/tcp 8080-8081/tcp 1080/tcp 1025/tcp 1167/tcp 8000/tcp 8100-8199/tcp 5672/tcp 4369/tcp 25672/tcp 15672/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

iptables -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i em2 -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i lo -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o em2 -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o lo -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -i em2 -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -i lo -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6081 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080:8081 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1025 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1167 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8100:8199 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5672 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4369 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25672 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 15672 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
```

traceroute 8.8.8.8

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.451 ms  0.382 ms  0.305 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: If the issue still happens when firewallid is disabled, is that likely to be relevant? What is the best way to get the config? I'll edit my OP with some more info.

Comment: How about traceroute?

Comment: SCPed the RPM over and was able to run one. I've attached the results. Looks like it's getting the gateway but nothing beyond it? Do I need to contact the gateway admin?

Comment: That's what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That did turn out to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This did turn out to be an issue outwith the server configuration.

A new internet connection was installed at the office, and the routing was updated to use the new connection. Apparently, one of the rules wasn't updated. As a result, the servers which were still routed through the old connection stopped working when the line was deactivated.